# How to place automatically created select fields in horizontal layout using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation, simple-form

Using Rails 4 with Simple Form & Zurb Foundation 5.

I'm stuck getting Simple Form to wrap divs around the automatically created select fields when using the input date_of_birth. The code I have so far is below:

```
<div class = "row">
<div class = "medium-12 columns">
    <%= form.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, 
                                   end_year: Date.today.year - 2, 
                                   start_year: Date.today.year - 90, 
                                   order: [:day, :month, :year]%>
</div>
</div>
```

This Simple Form code creates [this (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gzfG.png) with the output HTML looking like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns">
    <div class="input date optional person_date_of_birth">
        <label class="date optional control-label" for="person_date_of_birth_3i">Date of birth</label>
        <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_3i" name="person[date_of_birth(3i)]">
            <option>...</option>
        </select>
        <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_2i" name="person[date_of_birth(2i)]">
            <option>...</option>
        </select>
        <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_1i" name="person[date_of_birth(1i)]">
            <option>...</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like [this (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLi9P.png) with HTML output something like the below where each select field is wrapped in a div so I can specify grid size.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns">
    <div class="input date optional person_date_of_birth">
        <label class="date optional control-label" for="person_date_of_birth_3i">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
            <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_3i" name="person[date_of_birth(3i)]">
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
            <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_2i" name="person[date_of_birth(2i)]">
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
            <select class="date optional" id="person_date_of_birth_1i" name="person[date_of_birth(1i)]">
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle might help.. have u tried using `float: left` ?

Comment: Would it help if you can add the classes `medium-4 columns` to the select tag?

Comment: @emaillenin `float:left` didn't work.

Comment: @Vimsha - Adding the `medium-4 columns` class to the select tag gets them all on the same row but the spacing ends up a bit funny. Might have to go this path if there's no way to wrap them in div tags. How do I pass this class to each select field using Simple Forms code above for date_of_birth? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `input_html` option to add the classes to each select

```
<div class = "row">
<div class = "medium-12 columns">
    <%= form.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, 
                                   end_year: Date.today.year - 2, 
                                   start_year: Date.today.year - 90, 
                                   order: [:day, :month, :year],
                                   input_html: {class: "medium-12 columns"}%>
</div>
</div>
```

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700418/how-to-wrap-every-select-of-date-select-with-a-div-in-rails) to add the div using jquery on document load like

```
$('select[id*="date_of_birth"]').wrapAll('<div class="medium-12 columns">');
```

Comment: I ended up getting the jQuery variation on document load to work. Used   `$('select[id*="date_of_birth"]').wrap('<div class="medium-4 columns">');` Thank you. It gave me the pixel perfect look I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Can just use CSS too:

```
  .medium-12.columns select {
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
  }
```