# The way to wrap each date select using simple_form for bootstrap 3

Tags: date, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, wrapper, simple-form

Is there a way to wrap each select in simple_form input as date?
Now I use this, but I want an extra wrapper for each select

```
config.wrappers :date_wrapper, class: 'form-group' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label, class: 'col-md-4 control-label'
  b.wrapper class: 'col-md-8 form-group date-selects' do |inputs|
    inputs.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    inputs.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    inputs.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
  end
end

= f.input :date, as: :date, wrapper: :date_wrapper
```

Produces this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6 date required">
    <label class="date required col-md-4 control-label" for="date_3i">
      Date
      <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8 form-group date-selects">
      <select aria-required="true" class="date required form-control" id="date_3i" name="date[date(3i)]" required="required">...</select>
      <select aria-required="true" class="date required form-control" id="date_2i"  name="date[date(2i)]" required="required">...</select>
      <select aria-required="true" class="date required form-control" id="date_1i"name="date[date(1i)]" required="required">...</select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap every select of date\_select with a div in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700418/how-to-wrap-every-select-of-date-select-with-a-div-in-rails)

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for this?